# Setting site name in installation profile

Tags: installation-profiles

I'm creating an installation profile. Currently, `hook_install()` contains only this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function myprofile_install() {
  \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('system.site')->set('name', 'My Site')->save();
}
```

Still, after installation is completed (using Drush) the site name is always "Drupal".

The code works if I paste it into Devel's *Execute PHP* after the site is installed.

Another option I tried is overriding system.site.yml within my profile, which won't load because I wrote `uuid: ''`. (I don't know how to leave the already-generated UUID.)

How can I set the site name during installation in my custom profile?

---

**EDIT**: I found out the following:

- The site name gets overwritten when the install configuration form is submitted by Drush, using the values provided by Drush (including site name)
- The installation profile must provide a translation of the site information for each enabled language (I have more than one). I assume I'll do this with the core module Configuration Translate.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `hook_install_tasks`.

The source of the issue was that Drush was filling in the install configuration form during the installation process. Because the form comes after the profile's `hook_install`, it will override whatever configuration we write in `hook_install`.

Using `hook_install_tasks` will work by defining a new install task for setting our preferred configuration, which Drupal will run **after** submitting the configuration form. See function `install_tasks()` in `core/includes/install.core.inc`, line 716.